# Changing port in docker-compose.yml

Tags: port, docker-compose

I'm learning how to use *docker-compose* following the official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

When browsing to http://myserver.com:5000 I have the expected result:

```
Hello World! I have been seen 1 times.
```

I would like to change the listening port to 5001 modifying the *docker-compose.yml* file as follow:

```
version: '2'
  services:
    web:
      build: .
      ports:
       - "5001:5001"
      volumes:
       - .:/code
      depends_on:
       - redis
    redis:
      image: redis
```

Unfortunately, after stop and removing the container (with 'docker-compose down') and start it again (with 'docker-compose up -d'), the connection to http://myserver.com:5001 is refused.

Any idea?

Comment: You've changed your application to listen on port 5001 too?

Answer (score 28):

You should change the external port only (the first port number in `xxxx:xxxx` which maps to `HOST:CONTAINER`)

```yaml
version: '2'
  services:
    web:
      build: .
      ports:
       - "5001:5000"
      volumes:
       - .:/code
      depends_on:
       - redis
    redis:
      image: redis
```

Link to documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports

Comment: Is the first port 5001 a host port, or is it a container port?

Comment: HOST:CONTAINER will update my answer to clarify