# How to tell docker to listen on different port?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have installed docker on RHEL 8 in effort to install DSpace (this is my first time using docker). When I run this:

```
sudo docker-compose -p d7 -f docker/docker-compose.yml -f docker/docker-compose-rest.yml up -d
```

I get:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dspacesolr (b0c0fcb64db0dff035277571753b5e644552d78f8dba5d271a2fed4e412f4ed0): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8983: bind: address already in use
```

I already have solr listening on 8983 for another app on this server and I assume that's what's causing the problem. If my assumption is correct, how do I tell docker to listen on a different port? I don't see anything obvious in docker-compose.yml to change.

Thanks!

Edit:
Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '3.7'
    networks:
      dspacenet:
    services:
      dspace-angular:
        container_name: dspace-angular
        environment:
          DSPACE_UI_SSL: 'false'
          DSPACE_UI_HOST: dspace-angular
          DSPACE_UI_PORT: '4000'
          DSPACE_UI_NAMESPACE: /
          DSPACE_REST_SSL: 'false'
          DSPACE_REST_HOST: localhost
          DSPACE_REST_PORT: 8080
          DSPACE_REST_NAMESPACE: /server
        image: dspace/dspace-angular:dspace-7_x
        build:
          context: ..
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        networks:
          dspacenet:
        ports:
        - published: 4000
          target: 4000
        - published: 9876
          target: 9876
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing port in docker-compose.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553265/changing-port-in-docker-compose-yml)

Comment: You're looking for a `ports:` block, with `8983` on the left-hand side.  When you change it, change _only_ the left-hand side; leave the right-hand side as it is.

Comment: @AlexanderSantos, if I understand correctly that changes the web port but not the dspacesolr port.

Comment: @DavidMaze, there isn't anything formatted like that. I added the docker-compose.yml contents to my original post. How would I know if I'm impacting the dspacesolr port?

Comment: @Chanel the port that conflicts to you is the port from host (i.e. "your PC"). You can keep the port it runs inside container and expose it into another port on host. `HOST:CONTAINER` is  the syntax, if you keep the application on 8080 (for example) you can do `5000:8080`. It will expose it on port 5000 for you "local"

Comment: @AlexanderSantos, sorry to be dense but do I change DSPACE_REST_PORT to something like : 5000:8080?

Comment: I was digging around and found a dspacesolr section in docker-compose-rest.yml. It shows published: 8983 and target: 8983. Which one do I change?

Comment: *Target* is equivalent to *container* and *published* to *host* port. I recommend reading this article, as it can clarify a bit more about how it works for you https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-compose-expose-vs-ports

Answer (score 0):

For future generations, go into docker/docker-compose-rest.yml and in the dspacesolr section, change ports>published to a different port.